# Rails: add addtional html into content_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my navigation, I need '.active' to tell user if they are in the current page. So I defined a helper to generate `li.active` dynamically.

```
def nav_link(link_text, link_path
  class_name = current_page?(link_path) ? 'active' : nil
  content_tag(:li, :class => class_name) do
    link_to link_text, link_path
  end
end
```

so it can generate

```
<li class="active">
<a href="/resources">Resources</a>
</li>
```

However, for one specific link, I want to add `<strong>` to the `<a>` inside `<li>` to make it stands out from others. How can I do it?

```
<li class="active">
<strong><a href="/resources">Resources</a></strong>
</li>
```

UPDATE:
From this

[image]

To this

[image]

Every nav link(e.g. `new`,`resources`, `videos`) all uses the `nav_link` helper. What I need, is a way to insert some html(or CSS) into the `resouces` link. To make it stands out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not make the change in `css`?

```
.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

You can certainly nest `content_tag` to add `strong` node:

```
def nav_link(link_text, link_path, additional_class = nil)
  class_name = current_page?(link_path) ? 'active' : nil
  content_tag(:li, :class => class_name) do
    content_tag(:strong) do 
      link_to link_text, link_path
    end
  end
end
```

Update:

You could check for "Resources" as follows to add the `strong` tag:

```
def nav_link(link_text, link_path, additional_class = nil)
  class_name = current_page?(link_path) ? 'active' : nil
  content_tag(:li, :class => class_name) do
    link = link_to(link_text, link_path)

    if link_text == 'Resources' 
      content_tag(:strong) { link }
    else
      link
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I may not be clear enough. The `nav_link` is applied to all the links. But for one of them, I want to add a `css class` to it. How? You can see my update for pics.

Comment: Is it possible to dynamically insert `css class` or code into it? Like adding addtional css class into the `:class => class_name`.

Comment: @cqcn1991, Sure, you'd need to manipulate the assignment of `class_name` variable in the method.  I'd also suggest this approach than the `strong` element.

Comment: But could you elaborate this with more detail? I cannot do `class_name + additional_css_class`, seems like I need to turn them into string and concatenate them? Or can the `:class =>` be able to accept `class array`?

Comment: You need to try out the options yourself, that's certainly the best way to learn.  If you have an array, concatenate them with a space separator using `Array#join(' ')`.  So if you have array of css classes `[ 'active', 'preferred' ]` then you can do `[ 'active', 'preferred' ].join(' ')`